# With Firefox, how can I get a cache entry as a file using its entry info

Tags: linux, firefox, cache

I use Firefox 58 on GNU/Linux Mint 18.3

If I visit `about:cache?storage=disk&context=`, I get a listing of cache entries; and if I click one, I see some meta-data, and then this sort of an octal dump of the contents:

```
00000000:  1f  8b  08  00  00  00  00  00  04  00  ec  bd  69  73  db  48  ............is.H
00000010:  b2  28  fa  f1  45  dc  5f  41  c1  1a  19  10  c1  55  3b  29  .(..E._A.....U;)
00000020:  90  d7  6d  bb  a7  1d  e3  de  2c  f7  f4  99  21  69  0f  08  ..m.....,...!i..
00000030:  80  12  da  20  c0  01  40  cb  6a  91  fd  db  5f  2e  55  40  ... ..@.j..._.U@
00000040:  61  a1  24  f7  99  f3  5e  c4  8d  db  33  86  88  aa  42  ad  a.$...^...3...B.
00000050:  59  b9  55  66  96  b6  4e  bc  46  92  c6  be  93  6a  c3  cf  Y.Uf..N.F....j..
```

and so on. But - I want the actually cached document/sequence-of-octets, as a file. Can I get that somehow? Through the browser UI or from the command-line based on the cache entry details?

Answer (score 1):

### Restore file with HEX data

**First**, remove the line numbers at the front and the characters at the end.

To do so you could copy the dump data to an editor using one of these:

- a multi-line cursor
- *search and replace:* search with the regular expression: `([0-9a-f]{8}:\s\s)|(.{16}($|\n))` and replace it to nothing.

**Second**, insert the pure hex-data you now have into an hex editor like e.g. https://hexed.it/, export / save the file and make sure you give the file the right file-ending, depending on the content-type.

Comment: So, I guess I could do that, but - I'm sure that stuff is sitting in some file on disk.

Comment: Well, it is but not as a readable file. If you have a look at *about:cache?storage=disk&context=*  you will see a property named: **Storage disk location**

Comment: But as I said they are encrypted for security reasons: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/982861

Comment: No, I don't see that.

Comment: Well, I am on Windows, but that I think it should be the same on Linux: https://imgur.com/3uxGWtU

Comment: that regex is incorrect, the line numbers are reported as hex so you need `([0-9a-f]{8}:\s\s)|(.{16}($|\n))`

Comment: Well, valid point @ArkadiyKukarkin - I just saw the excerpt in the question and didn't realize this must be hex too. - Thanks, I just corrected the answer